# How to retrieve a Set of String from the field of each element in a List of objects that is contained in an object?

Tags: java, list, java-8, set, java-stream

I have an Object with multiple fields. One of the fields is a `List<Object2>`.

I want to recuperate a List (or a Set because I don't need the duplicated) of all the names (`Object2.getName()`) of the items Object2.

I tried to do it as follows:

```
getList().stream()
        .map(Object::getListObject2)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet())
        .stream()
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

It returns a `Set<Object2>`, but not a `Set/List<Object2.getName()>`.

Also, I'm concerned about the complexity of the stream.

Thank you.

Comment: you can use `.distinct().collect(Collectors.toList())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to collect then re-stream. Just call getName.
How about this ?

```
getList().stream()
    .map(Object::getListObject2)
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .map(Object2::getName)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: And if I want a `List<Object2>` returned, I can modify the last line with `.distinct().collect(Collectors.toList())` as @Jeremy Grand suggested. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
 getList().stream()
          .flatmap(x -> x.getListObject2().map(Object2::getName))
          .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```